# Change variables when radio button is checked

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to condense my code? I have 5 Radio Buttons and below is my code. Currently, the code changes the values of my minimum and maximum public variables depending on which radio box is checked. This was the first way i found to change the radio buttons in real time so that the rest of my code will have the correct values for my variables minimum and maximum.

```
Private Sub ArtyCalculator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    rBtnMortar.Checked = True
End Sub
Private Sub rBtnMortar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnMortar.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnMortar.Checked Then
        Min = 45
        Max = 65
        NameofArty = "Mortar"
        txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        txtMinimum.Refresh()
        txtMaximum.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnHowitzer_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnHowitzer.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnHowitzer.Checked Then
        Min = 75
        Max = 150
        NameofArty = "Howitzer"
        txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        txtMinimum.Refresh()
        txtMaximum.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnFieldArtillery_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnFieldArtillery.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnFieldArtillery.Checked Then
        Min = 75
        Max = 150
        NameofArty = "Field Artillery"
        txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        txtMinimum.Refresh()
        txtMaximum.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnGunBoat_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnGunBoat.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnGunBoat.Checked Then
        Min = 50
        Max = 100
        NameofArty = "Gun Boat"
        txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        txtMinimum.Refresh()
        txtMaximum.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnTank_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnTank.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnTank.Checked Then
        Min = 1
        Max = 40
        NameofArty = "Tank"
        txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        txtMinimum.Refresh()
        txtMaximum.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: One way would be to use a class and a PropertyGrid.

Comment: At least put all those lines into a single function which takes [the only variables between them all] min, max, and nameOfArty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a couple options.

### Option 1:

```
Private Sub RefreshArtillerySelection(Min As Integer, Max As integer, Name As String)
    Me.Min = Min
    Me.Max = Max
    Me.NameOfArty = Name
    txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
    txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
    txtMinimum.Refresh()
    txtMaximum.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnMortar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnMortar.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnMortar.Checked Then RefreshArtillerySelection(45, 65, "Mortar")
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnHowitzer_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnHowitzer.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnHowitzer.Checked Then RefreshArtillerySelection(75, 150, "Howitzer")
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnFieldArtillery_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnFieldArtillery.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnFieldArtillery.Checked Then RefreshArtillerySelection(75, 150, "Field Artillery")
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnGunBoat_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnGunBoat.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnGunBoat.Checked Then RefreshArtillerySelection(50, 100, "Gun Boat")
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnTank_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnTank.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnTank.Checked Then RefreshArtillerySelection(1, 40, "Tank")
End Sub
```

### Option 2:

Define this class:

```
Public Class Artillery
     Public Property Name As String
     Public Property MinRange As Integer
     Public Property MaxRange As Integer
     Public Sub New(Name As String, Min As Integer, Max As Integer)
        Me.Name = Name
        Me.MinRange = Min
        Me.MaxRange = Max
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then add this to Load:

```
Private ArtilleryMap As New Dictionary(Of RadioButton, Artillery)

Private Sub ArtyCalculator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ArtilleryMap.Add(rBtnMortar, New Artillery("Mortar", 45, 65))
    ArtilleryMap.Add(rBtnHowitzer, New Artillery("Howitzer", 75, 150))
    ArtilleryMap.Add(rBtnMortar, New Artillery("Field Artillery", 75, 150))
    ArtilleryMap.Add(rBtnMortar, New Artillery("Gun Boat", 50, 100))
    ArtilleryMap.Add(rBtnMortar, New Artillery("Tank", 1, 40))

    rBtnMortar.Checked = True
End Sub
```

And make one generic event handler that handles all the radiobuttons:

```
Private Sub Artillery_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnMortar.CheckedChanged, rBtnHowitzer.CheckedChanged, rBtnFieldArtillery.CheckedChanged, rBtnGunBoat.CheckedChanged, rBtnTank.CheckedChanged

    Dim radio As RadioButton = TryCast(sender, RadioButton)
    If radio Is Nothing OrElse Not ArtilleryMap.ContainsKey(radio) Then Return

    Dim art As Artillery = ArtilleryMap(radio)

    Me.Min = art.Min
    Me.Max = ar.Max
    Me.NameOfArty = art.Name
    txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & art.Min
    txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & art.Max
    txtMinimum.Refresh()
    txtMaximum.Refresh()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your Reply I choose to try option two and it works well!

Answer (score 0):

To expand on djv's comment...

```
Private Sub SetArty(name As String, min As Integer, max As Integer)
    Me.Min = min
    Me.Max = max
    Me.NameofArty = name
    txtMinimum.Text = "Minimum Distance: " & Min
    txtMaximum.Text = "Maximum Distance: " & Max
    txtMinimum.Refresh()   ' Not really necessary, but you had it in your code
    txtMaximum.Refresh()
End Sub

Private Sub rBtnMortar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnMortar.CheckedChanged
    If rBtnMortar.Checked Then SetArty("Mortar", 45, 65)
End Sub
```

Condense the other event handlers in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I don`t write complete code in answers here (there is a neighbor forum for that purpose: [CODE REVIEW](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) )  but i will make an exception this time.

1. create a class (`ArtyValues`) to to make objects of your arty values. using a class you will be able to reuse it for more "artilary" radio buttons and your code wil be much more maintainable.
2. store instances of that class inside a dictionary (`ArtyDictionary`) when the key to each class instance is a radio button (also in the future, if you will need to expend arty objects it will be much easier)
3. its better to declare your dictionary as **property** and not as a **field** (its not must but it is a good practice).
4. make only one method to make changes in the GUI (`RadArtyChckChanged()`) , all radio button controls `CheckedChanged` event will call that method and will pass the `sender` (the radio button control that was clicked) in order to extract the matching  instance.

Example:

```
   Public Class ArtyCalculator

        Public _ArtyDictionary As Dictionary(Of RadioButton, ArtyValues)
        Public Property ArtyDictionary As Dictionary(Of RadioButton, ArtyValues)
            Get
                If IsNothing(_ArtyDictionary) Then
                    _ArtyDictionary = New Dictionary(Of RadioButton, ArtyValues)
                    LoadDictionary()
                    Return _ArtyDictionary
                Else
                    Return _ArtyDictionary
                End If
            End Get
            Set(value As Dictionary(Of RadioButton, ArtyValues))
                _ArtyDictionary = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Sub LoadDictionary()
            ' initilize Arty objects
            Dim Mortar As New ArtyValues(45, 65, "Mortar")
            Dim Howitzer As New ArtyValues(75, 150, "Howitzer")
            Dim Field_Artillery As New ArtyValues(75, 150, "Field_Artillery")
            Dim Gun_Boat As New ArtyValues(50, 100, "Gun_Boat")
            Dim Tank As New ArtyValues(1, 40, "Tank")
            ' create the dictionary, keys will be radiobuton and value will be the ArtyValues instance that fit the radiobutton 
            _ArtyDictionary.Add(rBtnMortar, Mortar)
            _ArtyDictionary.Add(rBtnHowitzer, Howitzer)
            _ArtyDictionary.Add(rBtnFieldArtillery, Field_Artillery)
            _ArtyDictionary.Add(rBtnGunBoat, Gun_Boat)
            _ArtyDictionary.Add(rBtnTank, Tank)
        End Sub

        Private Sub ArtyCalculator_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            rBtnMortar.Checked = True
        End Sub

        Private Sub rBtnMortar_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnMortar.CheckedChanged
            RadArtyChckChanged(sender)
        End Sub

        Private Sub rBtnHowitzer_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnHowitzer.CheckedChanged
            RadArtyChckChanged(sender)
        End Sub

        Private Sub rBtnFieldArtillery_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnFieldArtillery.CheckedChanged
            RadArtyChckChanged(sender)
        End Sub

        Private Sub rBtnGunBoat_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnGunBoat.CheckedChanged
            RadArtyChckChanged(sender)
        End Sub

        Private Sub rBtnTank_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rBtnTank.CheckedChanged
            RadArtyChckChanged(sender)
        End Sub

        Private Sub RadArtyChckChanged(sender As Object)
            Dim obj As ArtyValues = ArtyDictionary(sender)
            Min = obj.Min
            Max = obj.Max
            NameofArty = obj.NameofArty
            txtMinimum.Text = obj.GetMinText()
            txtMaximum.Text = obj.GetMaxText()
            txtMinimum.Refresh()
            txtMaximum.Refresh()
        End Sub

        Public Min As Integer
        Public Max As Integer
        Public NameofArty As String
    End Class

    Public Class ArtyValues

        Public Min As Integer
        Public Max As Integer
        Public NameofArty As String

        Sub New(ByVal min As Integer, ByVal max As Integer, ByVal nameofarty As String)
            Me.Min = min
            Me.Max = max
            Me.NameofArty = nameofarty
        End Sub

        Public Function GetMinText() As String
            Return "Minimum Distance: " & Min
        End Function

        Public Function GetMaxText() As String
            Return "Maximum Distance: " & Max
        End Function
    End Class
```